# Should the reference count of PyObject* created by a cdef public function be manually decreased

Tags: cython

I want to export a python class to be used in C++:

```py
class Object:
    def method(self):
        pass
    
cdef public object create_object() with gil:
    return Object()

cdef public void py_method(object obj) with gil:
    obj.method()  # obj is expected to have method()
```

Then the generated header file will have the following functions:

```
__PYX_EXTERN_C PyObject *create_object(void);
__PYX_EXTERN_C void py_method(PyObject *);
```

---

**My question is: should I also have a function like**

```
from cpython cimport Py_XDECREF, PyObject
cdef public void destroy_object(PyObject* obj) with gil:
    Py_XDECREF(obj)
```

**to avoid memory leak?**

Then these functions may be used in C++ code like:

```cpp
auto obj = create_object()
py_method(obj)

// Finally
destroy_object(obj)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should decrement it when calling it from C++. You could do it the way you propose or you could skip the definition of `destroy_object` and just use `Py_XDECREF` in C++.

Other things you should consider:

- `create_object` can return `NULL` if it's raised a Python exception so check for that
- RAII wrappers are always a good idea (to handle the reference counting)

Comment: Thanks for verifying that. For the first point you pointed out, suppose the exception is handled by a `try...except` block, then it seems there's no way to manually return `NULL`, since the return type is `object`. Do I have to return a `None` and check for `Py_None` in C++?

Comment: You can return what you like and check for it in c++! Although `None` is probably a good choice. It might be better to just let the exception propagate though (and Cython will automatically return `NULL`)